# External USB3 HITATCHI Hard drive dis not found

Tags: external-hard-drive, hard-drive-recovery

Hello I have a USB3 Hitatchi external HDD. If i connected to a PC with Windows 10 or Raspberry Pi the Disc is not shown and not available.
What could be the probelm ? Is there any USB driver need? 
How to backup the data of this Disk?

Comment: Can you take the drive itself from its case and connect directly to a PC (via SATA interface)?

Comment: it's in a case with a usb3-SS interface.

Comment: Can you at least check it with another USB cable? or the current cable with another device? What about the power source? The point is the disk itself may be OK but some component of your USB bridge may be faulty. Often there is a standard SATA HDD inside, hence my first comment. Connecting via SATA would take these additional components out of the equation.

Comment: I connected with two several USB cable to my Windos 10 also Windows XP PC and Raspberry Pi. In all six cases the LED is on an i also can feel that the engin in the disc allready rotate.

Comment: Do you have Linux in RPi? If so connect it, open the terminal and run `lsusb`. If it detects a new USB device but you can't mount it as a storage device (or if not recognized as such in Disks, for example) then the drive inside is likely to be defective. If it doesn appear as a new USB device then the problem is at the USB bridge and the drive itself may or may not be fine.